# A concise definition for fairness problem

Tags: optimization

I was reading the following lines from [this paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v98/cotter19a/cotter19a.pdf):

> To highlight some of the challenges that arise in non-convex
> constrained optimization, consider the specific example of
> constraining a fairness metric. We cast the fairness problem as that
> of minimizing some empirical loss subject to one or more fairness
> constraints. One of the simplest examples of such is the following:
>
> \begin{equation} \min _{\theta \in \Theta} \frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{x, y
> > \in S} \ell(f(x ; \theta), y)  \end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation} \text { s.t. } \frac{1}{|S|} \sum_{x \in S_{\min }}
> > 1_{f(x ; \theta)>0} \geq \frac{0.8}{|S|} \sum_{x \in S} 1_{f(x ;
> > \theta)>0} \end{equation}

From what I understand a fairness problem is trying to yield better result for a minority in the population. I was trying to find a concise definition for fairness problem/metric but looking at online resources including [this course](https://fairmlclass.github.io), all I find looks like political agenda (Disclaimer: I'm not conveying that it is either good or bad).

Answer (score 0):

From Michele Donini et al. "[Empirical Risk Minimization Under Fairness Constraints](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08626)" (Jan 2020):

> In the literature there are different definitions of fairness of a model or learning algorithm, but there is not yet a consensus on which definition is most appropriate. In this paper, we introduce a general notion of fairness which encompasses some previously used notions and it allows to introduce new ones by specifying the loss function used below.

The rest of the paper is dedicated to developing this idea further. It seems that this topic is still being developed, since this paper is addressing the perceived gap in a consensus definition.